# How to improve code clarity in nested try-except-else clauses?

Tags: python, exception

Sometimes I have a cascade of different things I can try to accomplish a task, e. g. If I need to get a record I can first try to find the record, and if this fails, I can create the missing record, and if this also fails, I can use a tape instead.

Failing is represented by throwing an exception my code needs to catch.

In Python this looks something like this:

```py
try:
  record = find_record()
except NoSuchRecord:
  try:
    record = create_record()
  except CreateFailed:
    record = tape
```

This already has the disadvantage of piling-up indentations.  If I have five options, this code won't look good.

But I find it even more problematic when there are also `else` clauses to the `try`-`except` clauses:

```py
try:
  record = find_record()
except NoSuchRecord:
  try:
    record = create_record()
  except CreateFailed:
    record = tape
    logger.info("Using a tape now")
  else:
    logger.info("Created a new record")
else:
  logger.info("Record found")
```

The `find_record()` and the corresponding `Record found` message are as far apart as possible which makes it hard to read code.  (Moving the code of the `else` clause directly into the `try` clause is only an option if this code is definitely not raising one of the exceptions caught in the `except` statement, so this is no general solution.)

Again, this ugliness gets worse with each added level of nesting.

Is there a nicer way to put this into Python code

1. without changing the behavior and
2. while keeping the `try` and the `except` clauses of one topic closely together and/or
3. maybe also avoiding the piling-up nesting and indenting?

Comment: Break this into two functions ?

Comment: Are you committed to using exceptions to signal unusual function outcomes? If `find_record` and `create_record` returned `None` on a failure instead of raising an exception, that might open up some design possibilities for your code block here.

Comment: If there are related failure conditions you might consider creating a custom ErrorHandler.

Comment: I'm talking about cases where I use stuff which raises exceptions, yes.  I'm not at liberty to change _these_.

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer. The design will be dictated by exactly what each function returns and/or can raise.

Comment: (For example, the `logger` methods clearly won't be raising the exceptions you are trying to catch here, but the answer will change based on what exceptions you *are* worried about being raised.)

Comment: @chepner I stumbled across this thing a lot, so I'd like to have a general approach, not a specialized which works only in one case.  Exceptions to be caught could be such general thins like `IndexError` or `ValueError`, so I'd like to keep the `try`-clause as small as possible to avoid catching other things unintentionally.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `for` loop to successively try variants:

```
for task, error in ((find_record, NoSuchRecord), (create_record, CreateFailed)):
    try:
        result = task()
    except error:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    # for..else is only entered if there was no break
    result = tape
```

If you need an `else` clause, you can provide it as a separate function:

```
for task, error, success in (
    (find_record, NoSuchRecord, lambda: logger.info("Record found")),
    (create_record, CreateFailed, lambda: logger.info("Created a new record"))
):
    try:
        result = task()
    except error:
        continue
    else:
        success()
        break
else:
    result = tape
    logger.info("Using a tape now")
```

Take note that the default case `tape` is *not* part of the variants - this is because it has no failure condition. If it should execute with the variants, it can be added as `(lambda: tape, (), lambda: None)`.

---

You can put this all into a function for reuse:

```
def try_all(*cases):
    for task, error, success in cases:
        try:
            result = task()
        except error:
            continue
        else:
            success()
            return result

try_all(
    (find_record, NoSuchRecord, lambda: logger.info("Record found")),
    (create_record, CreateFailed, lambda: logger.info("Created a new record")),
    (lambda: tape, (), lambda: logger.info("Using a tape now")),
)
```

In case the tuples seem difficult to read, a `NamedTuple` can be used to name the elements. This can be mixed with plain tuples:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Callable, Union, Tuple
from functools import partial

class Case(NamedTuple):
    task: Callable
    error: Union[BaseException, Tuple[BaseException, ...]]
    success: Callable


try_all(
    Case(
        task=find_record,
        error=NoSuchRecord,
        success=partial(logger.info, "Record found")),
    (
        create_record, CreateFailed,
        partial(logger.info, "Created a new record")),
    Case(
        task=lambda: tape,
        error=(),
        success=partial(logger.info, "Using a tape now")),
)
```

Comment: You could have a third factory `lambda: tape` that does away with the need for the `else` clause on the `for` loop.

Comment: @chepner The ``tape`` is not a variant since it is not allowed to fail.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It doesn't matter since it wont?

Comment: Yes, but `lambda: tape` is also guaranteed not to raise anything (at least, nothing you were going to catch). Let `error` be some custom exception like `class CannotHappen(Exception): pass`.

Comment: The general case could of course raise stuff, but actually, you can pass `()` as value for the `except` statement, then it doesn't catch anything.

Comment: Like I said before, the general case makes this question unanswerable.

Comment: @chepner, here is an answer :)  Why do you still say it's unanswerable?

Comment: @Alfe Thanks for the hint of using ``()``, I had not thought of that. Added it as a suggestion at the end.

Comment: Actually I like this.  And if the factories are complex, I think I will factor them out into single functions (like @hansolo proposed).  This only makes trouble if the code for the different cases were supposed to have some inner-function side effects like setting local variables etc.  But then this all needs to be going into the return values.

Comment: I fell this made code more complicated, there are so many moving parts you need to understand before you can understand the flow. The original flow is quite simple. try to find record if not create new one again if not user a default record

Comment: Because you won't commit to what any of the functions you want to call may or may not raise. Also, I don't find this any more readable than your current nested `try` statement, and again in general, I can't extrapolate either approach to more complicated chains.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Also, if you are going to add an `else` clause to the `for` loop, you don't have to start with `result = tape`; put that in the `else` clause as well.

Comment: @DevKhadka In my simple example, sure.  I wouldn't apply the more complex version for these <10 lines.  But in my real cases, such things often go over several screens, that's why I dislike separating the `else` from the `try` clause so much.

Answer (score 3):

You could break that into multiple functions ?

```
def handle_missing():
    try:
        record = create_record()
    except CreateFailed:
        record = tape
        logger.info("Using a tape now")
    else:
        logger.info("Created a new record")
    return record


def get_record():
    try:
        record = find_record()
    except NoSuchRecord:
        record = handle_missing()
    else:
        logger.info("Record found")
    return record
```

And then you'd use it like,

```
record = get_record()
```

Comment: Yes, I see, it factored each indentation level out into a single function :)  That seems rather simple, yes.

Comment: Yeah, if you see yourself writing `try..except..else` nesting, you could almost always break that into multiple functions and the code will be more readable and easy to maintain :)

Answer (score 0):

I think following code is more readable and clean. Also I am sure in real problem we need some parameters to be sent to "find_record" and "create_record" functions like id, some, values to create new record. The factory solution need those parameters also be listed in tuple

```py
def try_create(else_return):
    try:
        record = create_record()
    except CreateFailed:
        record = else_return
        logger.info("Using a tape now")
    else:
        logger.info("Created a new record")

def try_find(else_call= try_create, **kwargs):
    try:
        record = find_record()
    except NoSuchRecord:
        try_create(**kwargs)
    else:
        logger.info("Record found") 



try_find(else_call=try_create, else_return=tape)
```