# How can I use loop code on try, except code?

Tags: python

Now I'm coding to get Change value (A day - A day of yesterday) and the data existing only working day so if no existing data of a day the code get KeyError.
so I used Try, Except code but...so messy..I wanna combine below code.

```
    ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=1)
    sydate = str(ydate)
    try:
        yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
    except KeyError:
        try:
            ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=2)
            sydate = str(ydate)
            yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
        except KeyError:
            try:
                ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=3)
                sydate = str(ydate)
                yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
            except KeyError:
                    try:
                    ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=4)
                    sydate = str(ydate)
                    yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
```

Comment: Put your code in a function with a `while True` loop and return the values at the end of the `try` block. If the `return` is not hit, the loop will do an other round.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to improve code clarity in nested try-except-else clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974694/how-to-improve-code-clarity-in-nested-try-except-else-clauses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a loop.

```py
for x in range(0, 5):
    ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=x)
    sydate = str(ydate)
    try:
        yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
    except KeyError:
        continue
```