# Breaking out of a try-except block

Tags: python

I have a nested try-except-finally block where I run several functions in succession (assuming the previous ones worked). I have a condition that I check at the start (which essentially checks if the function has already been run that day) and if this statement is false, I want to jump straight to the finally.

I can do this by simply forcing an error to occur (i.e. writing x=1/0 but it seems there should be a better way to do this).

My code looks like this:

```
error = False
conditions = False

try:
    # Do stuff here
    if not condition:
        # Here I want to go directly to finally
except Exception:
    error = True
else:
    try:
        # Do stuff here
    except Exception:
        error = True
    else:
        try:
            # Do stuff here
        except Exception:
            error = True
finally:
    if error:
        # Report that an error occurred
    else:
        # Report that everything went well
```

Comment: If this is inside a function, `return`? Wouldn't throwing an error have the side effect that `error` would then be `True` rather than `False`?

Comment: This is not inside a function, this is inside of main execution of the script, executing a bunch of functions. It doesn't matter that much if error is wrongly assigned in this case, the logic in the finally statement won't care as long as it knows that the condition is false.

I didnt think of that when I wrote the example but that is not a concern :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Why do you have several nested exception handlers? Do they all have the same ``except`` block in your actual code? It might be easier to flatten the exception handling instead of orchestrating the control flow between the exception handlers.

Comment: if it's not inside a function `pass` will suffice

Comment: Looking again this could all be rewritten as one `try`/`catch`. Whatever's in `finally`/`if` goes in the `catch` block, whatever's in `finally`/`else` just goes at the end of the `try` block. Not executing the rest because an error got thrown is what would already happen. Then the skip just becomes `if condition: <things that get skipped otherwise>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to improve code clarity in nested try-except-else clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974694/how-to-improve-code-clarity-in-nested-try-except-else-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

To use MisterMiyagi's excellent wording in the comments to this answer, it inverts the logic to proceed only when the condition is met.

```
error = False
conditions = False

try:
    # Do stuff here
except Exception:
    error = True
else:
    if condition:  # The inverted condition moved here.
        try:
            # Do stuff here
        except Exception:
            error = True
        else:
            try:
                # Do stuff here
            except Exception:
                error = True
finally:
    if error:
        # Report that an error occurred
    else:
        # Report that everything went well
```

Comment: How is that functionally different from the question code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It does what the OP wants? The question code does not; it just says "# Here I want to go directly to finally" but doesn't do that. This code does that.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, not sure why I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Comment: @FredrikNilsson You're welcome! I found it complicated too and spend several minutes pondering over it. Then finally it clicked, and *then* it seemed obvious. 

Comment: @Jesper I get that the code does that. I'm asking *how* it does that. At a glance, it is almost identical to the question code. Perhaps you could spare a few words to explain the intuition, so that other people do not have to compare every line against the original? Perhaps something like "invert the logic to *proceed* only when the condition is met"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh, I'm sorry, I totally misunderstood your comment as "That's not functionally different from the question code!" Yes, you're absolutely right, it should be explained. Your explanation is so well and succinctly stated that I feel embarrassed to add it as if it were my own, but I'll add it with reference to you.